# thick bezier curve consist of lines in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, bezier, curve

I created bezier curve in C#. I compute result points of curve in some interval and I connect these points with a lines (g.drawLine). When I want curve which is 1px fat, all is right. But when I want thick this curve, occours problem. This problem is that connections individual lines is not pretty. Situation is ilustrate on zoom picture:

http://ryska.webzdarma.cz/bezier.png

Some tips how solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the mention of `g.drawLine` I would say this is `WinForms`. In that case, all you need to do is call

[Graphics.DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines.aspx)

instead of `DrawLine`. This will draw all the segments as one connected line.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making your curve out of several `LineSegment` objects, and specify `IsSmoothJoin = true;`